# Is this possible to an Interface inherit constants and methods from Super Interface in java?

Tags: java, oop

I know an Interface extends another Interface in java.So, Is this possible to inheriting constants and methods from the super interface.If i have any restrictions on inheriting then please guide me to get knowledge about it

Comment: there are no constants in Java, do you mean `static final`?

Comment: Interface contains constants like a variable declared in static final.I meant like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by extending constants?! all child interfaces/classes inherit ALL constants and methods from the super class/interface

Comment: @Saravanan Then I have answered your question :)